# Convert xlsx file to pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to convert an xlsx file to pdf.

I found libraries on how to convert html to pdf, but in the case that I want to convert an xlsx file to pdf I found that I have to extract the data and then create a pdf file as in the case of the [pdfMake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

xlsx is just a layout,
PDF is just a printout,

so any xlsx reader can print to PDF, (simplest to program is Apache/Soffice)

If you need to do it by code there are hundreds of ways your code can be written.

JavaScript is probably the worst language for the task, unless running a binary via command line. Thus I could script that view to print by JS, but would not bother as there are more efficient libraries.

[image]